# Get Google Form Response number into Response sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-forms, google-forms-api

I have a google form saving responses in a google sheet. Somehow the form line number and the form responses have gotten out of sync. I, looking for a way to iterate through the current responses and input a the response number into a cell in the response sheet.

[image: Response Number Example]

My hunch is to grab the response array form.getResponses() and use indexOf() but I cant seem to make it work. When trying to get the indexOf(timestamp) I get -1 which is not found in the array. Any ideas?

Comment: if you wish to know which line a certain response is on the use the onFormSubmit for a spreadsheet and e.range.rowStart will be the line that the response was written to.

Comment: FWIW, if a user resubmits a response then the modified row (`e.range.rowStart`) will be the row of the original submission.

Comment: Hi. As I recall, the timestamp isn't treated as a response, per se. However, there is a method [getTimestamp()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#gettimestamp) to return the timestamp and you need to use this to if you want to compare timestamps.

Comment: The rows in the sheet do not match to response numbers. They did on the first sheet but after some edits the original linked sheet became corrupt and stopped receiving responses, I had to link a new sheet and since then the response numbers and rows in the form data do not correlate. I have 800+ responses and Id like to find a way to iterate over them to find their response number, I thought I could pull the array which includes the timestamps, then search for each timestamp in my sheet against the array to find the index which should be the response number, so im getting timestamp from sheet.

Comment: What is the origin of the response numbers?

Comment: @Cooper I think the OP means the response number as shown in the referenced image. It's just the sequence number.

Comment: `I had to link a new sheet and since then the response numbers and rows in the form data do not correlate.` When you unlink a sheet and link a new sheet, the Form updates ALL the responses to the new sheet. So, in a manner of speaking, you have `form.getResponses()` (plus the timestamps) in that newly linked sheet. Would you please advise 1) how many responses are on the new sheet (compared to the 816 in the form? and 2) Have any users been able to modify their initial &/or subsequent submissions? If yes, you will NOT see these as new rows on the Response sheet.

Comment: @Tedinoz but I believe sequential numbering like that can get confusing if users can edit their answers.

Comment: When I linked the new sheet, they were not correlated 1:1, I did account for the header offset.

Comment: I currently have 843 responses in the form and only 842 in the sheet. I can lookup responses and they have different offsets. Response 100 is 87 in sheet, 200 is 177, 300 is 270, 400 is 359, etc etc. There have been responses deleted manually both before and after the new sheet was started.

Comment: `I believe sequential numbering like that can get confusing if users can edit their answers.` This may well be but I am just  telling you how the system works. A resubmission does NOT append a new response on the linked spreadsheet, it will edit the original response.

Comment: JCOENG, I don't know what expectations you have for this question. With respect, IMHO, the ability of users to constructively assist is limited by a lack of data and knowledge of manual and other adjustments. What are your thoughts, expectations at this stage?

Comment: I tried several methods of pulling the records and using timestamps to find the 'record' position in the array. The result was inconsistent. I was unable to correlate the form.getResponses() array index position with the response view number. Here's my code if anyone else wants to try,

Comment: function getFormIndex(){

  for(var i = formHeader; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] != '') {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses();
      if(formSubmitted.length < 1) {
        console.log("Skipping due to responses length");
        continue;
      }
      for(var j=0; j < formSubmitted.length; j++) { 
        if(timestamp.valueOf() == formSubmitted[j].getTimestamp().valueOf()) {
          formSheet.getRange(i+1, iDIndex+1).setValue(j+1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}